# Android Studio - Read and Write to/from file in local storage within a folder

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio

So I'm trying to read and write to and from a file that is inside a folder within the app's directory. So the path is something like "package/userFiles/'insert file name here'" but I can't find a way to do it anywhere.

I haven't been able to test this yet but the below is the code I've got for writing a quick and simple string to the file. If you could take a look over that I would be grateful, and if at all possibly give me some direction over how to read from the file.

```
FileOutputStream outputStream;
File path = new File(getFilesDir(),"userFiles");
path.mkdirs();
File mypath =new File(path,newFileNameText);
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
    String defaultMessage = "Empty File";
    out.write(defaultMessage.getBytes());
    out.close();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditFileContents.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,newFileNameText);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can see the code starts a new activity, it is this activity from which I would like to be able to read the contents of the file.

Comment: `something like "package/userFiles/'insert file name here'"`. No. Not at all. Please find out what the path really is.

Comment: Reading is nearly the same as writing. Change Output to Input and write to read.

Comment: Thanks but trying to create the file input stream with the mypath shown above results in it saying "openFileInput (java.lang.String) in ContextWrapper can not be applied to (java.io.File)".

Comment: If you change Output in FileOutputStream to Input then what do you get?